# How to have trigger fire after a (conditional) insert in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I am trying to have a trigger fire and insert data into various tables.  However, the process will differ so i was going to create two separate triggers. I've learned thus far how to have a trigger fire after every insert into a table. How can i have a trigger fire ONLY if the IDs are correlated to a certain primary key (id) from another table? I want the trigger to only fire on survey_cycles correlated to Form_IDs of '777' from the Form table. Form_ID and Survey_Cycle are joined at form_id. The bare bones table structure for both of these tables are below:

```
*Survey_Cycle:*
survey_Cycle_id
survey_form_id

*Survey_Form:*
Survey_Form_Id
```

My current trigger code is below:

```
create or replace TRIGGER Survey_Sample
AFTER INSERT
ON Survey_Cycle
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

Survey_Cycle_Id Number;
pSurvey_Cycle_Id Number;

BEGIN

Insert into Survey_Cycle_Sample
(Survey_Cycle_ID, Stat_Method_Id, Create_Dt, Create_User_Id, Modify_Dt, Modify_User_Id, Effective_Dt, Inactive_Dt, Survey_Cycle_Sample_Tx)
Values
(:NEW.Survey_Cycle_Id, 0, trunc(sysdate, 'HH'), 1, null, null, null, null, null);

Insert into Survey_Cycle_Period
(Survey_Cycle_Id, Survey_Cycle_Period_Open_Dt, Survey_Cycle_Period_Close_Dt, Survey_Period_Type_Cd, Create_Dt, Create_User_Id, Modify_Dt, Effective_Dt,     Inactive_Dt, Survey_Cycle_Period_Due_Dt, Survey_Cycle_Actual_Close_Dt)
Values
(:NEW.Survey_Cycle_Id, trunc(sysdate, 'HH'), trunc(sysdate + 1), 'Initial', sysdate, 1, null, null, null, sysdate - 1, null);

END;
```

Comment: Triggers do not fire based on values but based on events (Insert/Update/Delete) on structures (Tables and specific column if needed). If this is a straightforward application logic, why not do away with the trigger altogether?

Comment: There's no way I'm aware of to specify a condition such as this. You'll need to have the trigger fire and then do the cross-table lookup from inside the trigger to determine if you need to update the other tables.

Comment: @ArtBajji because I need to have the records update / insert as soon as i insert the rows into Survey_Sample. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If survey_sample table is inserted at multiple places in your application code then you need to have the trigger fire for every insert and perform the check inside your trigger to proceed with further inserts into other tables or not. If survey_sample table is inserted at a few places in your application code, then see if you can change your application code to handle this logic without the need for the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a trigger which calls a stored procedure, and let it decide whether do (or not) additional processing. Here's an example:

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table survey_cycle
  2    (survey_cycle_id number constraint pk_sc primary key,
  3     survey_form_id  number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table survey_form
  2    (survey_form_id  number constraint pk_sf primary key);

Table created.

SQL>
```

A procedure, which - for the ID passed to it - checks whether such an ID exists in the SURVEY_FORM table. If not, `SELECT` will fail (i.e. raise `NO_DATA_FOUND`) so the procedure won't do anything. If it exists, it'll execute additional code (such as inserts into two other tables; instead of that, I'm just displaying the appropriate message).

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_survey (par_survey_form_id in number)
  2  is
  3    l_survey_form_id survey_form.survey_form_id%type;
  4  begin
  5    select survey_form_id
  6      into l_survey_form_id
  7      from survey_form
  8      where survey_form_id = par_survey_form_id;
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Here goes INSERT INTO survey_cycle_sample and survey_cycle_period');
 11  exception
 12    when no_data_Found then
 13      -- there's no ID like PAR_SURVEY_FORM_ID, so - do nothing
 14      null;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

The trigger is very simple:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_survey_cycle
  2    after insert on survey_cycle
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    p_survey(:new.survey_form_id);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Finally, testing: 777 is the "existing" ID which will cause additional inserts.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> insert into survey_form values (777);

1 row created.

SQL> --
SQL> insert into survey_cycle values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into survey_cycle values (2, 777);
Here goes INSERT INTO survey_cycle_sample and survey_cycle_period

1 row created.

SQL>
```